# Select from table based on the latest entry in another table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `WHERE` clause in a query that needs to see whether the latest entry in a related table meets certain criteria. However, I'm not able to inject the PK of the top query directly into the clause for a number of different reasons.

Is there any way to rewrite the following query to depend on the outer alias (ie. make ALIAS.pk work)? foo has a composite primary key.

```
(SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT n.val1, n.val2 FROM (
             SELECT * FROM foo f
             WHERE f.val0 = 100 AND f.outerid = ALIAS.pk
             ORDER BY f.date DESC
         ) n
         WHERE n.rownum = 1
    ) t
    WHERE t.val1 = 1 AND t.val2 = 2
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM dual) = 1
```

Edit: Outer table (bar):

`id     name    city
 1      Bob     London
 2      Mike    Atlanta
 3      Susan   Toronto`

Inner table (foo):

`outerid    date        val1    val2    val100    fk1    fk2    fk3
 1          2014-11-11  1       2       100       11     523    15
 1          2014-11-11  1       2       101       14     12     87
 1          2014-11-10  1       2       100       17     1667   12
 2          2014-11-11  1       1       100       91     12     188`

The primary key for foo is a composite key over fk1..3. 
So what I need is to select the latest entry from foo that corresponds to a certain user and check that it has certain characteristics.

Edit 2:
`SELECT CASE WHEN ({inner query})=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END WHERE id = 1` should return "1" `SELECT SELECT CASE WHEN ({inner query})=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END WHERE  id = 2` should return "0".

Comment: Please post some example of your data structure and desired output

Answer (score 1):

This may give you the output you require:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM bar b
     INNER JOIN
       (SELECT DISTINCT
               f.outerid
        FROM
          (SELECT f.outerid
                , f.val1
                , f.val2
                , f.date
                , max(f.date) OVER
                    (PARTITION BY f.outerid
                     ORDER BY f.date) max_date
           FROM foo f
           WHERE f.val0 = 100) f
        WHERE f.date = f.max_date
        AND f.val1 = 1
        AND f.val2 = 2) f
       ON (f.outerid = b.id)
```

Comment: This works exactly as requested in my first edit with very little modification. However it seems I was slightly too eager when simplifying the problem. I've edited again to add a more representative query.